# The Page type field visibility condition not working

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

The Page type field visibility condition is not working for me. Am I missing anything here?

[image]

CampaignType is a dropdown field.

[image]

GetInTouchTheme field is always visible. It doesn't show/hide based on the CampaignType selection.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few minor syntax errors.  Make sure the `GetInTouchTheme` field has the "Depends on another field" option checked.

Then simply place the macro syntax below in the macro box.

`CampaignType.Value == "Maternity"`